# Technical English-Chinese Dictionary

Tags: dictionary

Do anyone know if it exists a professional English-Chinese and Chinese-English Technical Dictionary?

Comment: What exactly is a *professional*/*technical* dictionary?!

Comment: "Technical" is a little too broad. Maybe http://dict.cnki.net/ is a good one for Chinese-English translation -- it has citations to academic papers. However, it's not authoritative. When I use it to translate a Chinese word into English, I have to validate the translation by looking up the definition of the English word in Wikipedia; vice versa. Anyway it's convenient, you can have a try.

Comment: Technical dictionaries are dictionaries with terminology in the fields of technology and science, in which you can find names that you do not find in "classical dictionaries", because they are very technical. You can find in these dictionaries, for example, all the translations of the name of components of a machine. I have one technical dictionary from Italian to English, and I was wondering if there is one from English to Chinese too. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment:

> Technical dictionaries are dictionaries with terminology in the fields of technology and science, in which you can find names that you do not find in "classical dictionaries", because they are very technical.

I would highly recommend the **21st Century English-Chinese Dictionary**

blurb from Amazon:

> The English-Chinese dictionary collects more than 70,000 entries. It includes over 10,000 new words. The phonetic is referred to the new edition from U.K. & U. S. Appendix includes the information of five countries: United Kingdom, United States, Canada, Australia & New Zealand; the military ranks of U.K. & U.S.; international famous companies; chemical elements; punctuation; the usage of numeral, date & time; comparison of metric system & metrology of U.K. & U.S.

entry-wise I'm not sure why Amazon only mentions 70,000 entries as Pleco calls it:

> the 280,000-entry 21st Century English-Chinese Dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia is the best. Search the English term in the English Wikipedia, and then click the Chinese Wikipedia link to link to the Chinese entry.

Answer (score 0):

I used http://www.mdbg.net/ to translate a number of terms in the theory of differential equations.  Later I checked the translations with a native Chinese mathematician who works in the UK, and he said that they were mostly good.  That's a limited set of evidence, but suggestive.

Answer (score -1):

For software terminology, the practical usages are in the translation memory in software translation management services.